# Why are there two queries in one annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

Below is an example from the Spring Data and Neo4j documentation, which demonstrates the usage of cypher queries.

```
// returns a Page of Actors that have a ACTS_IN relationship to the movie node with the title equal to movieTitle parameter.
    @Query(value = "MATCH (movie:Movie {title={0}})<-[:ACTS_IN]-(actor) RETURN actor", countQuery= "MATCH (movie:Movie {title={0}})<-[:ACTS_IN]-(actor) RETURN count(actor)")
    Page<Actor> getActorsThatActInMovieFromTitle(String movieTitle, PageRequest page);
```

what's the use of the second query "countQuery=..."? Does it play any role in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#reference_programming_model_annotatedQueries). The relevant section:

> If it is required that paged results return the correct total count,
>   the @Query annotation can be supplied with a count query in the
>   countQuery attribute. This query is executed separately after the
>   result query and its result is used to populate the number of elements
>   on the Page.